Picking "Absolute Time" in Matlab Simulink crashes Model Advisor
I have been tasked with the generation of C code for a Matlab Simulink model that uses several built-in blocks. Model Advisor suggests me to change the options in Code Generation > Interface to make sure that the system is using "Absolute Time". However, doing so and running any of the available checks results in the Simulink crashing.
I have already extended the Java Heap Memory to its maximum available space, changed some of the time-dependent blocks in the code and tinkered with the model, but all to no avail.
Is there any common cause for this kind of error? If so, is there some specific option I should check somewhere or any kind of mistake that may be propagating throughout the model?
